# Shouldn't the Thevenin equivalent have the same behavior (regarding the transfer function) as the circuit it's derived from?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, transfer-function, thevenin

I am new to electronics and I have a little trouble applying the basics I learnt so far. My problem is basically that I don't understand why we consider the second circuit below as the Thevenin equivalent, even though the behaviour of the transfer function is  different.

[image]

Here you can see the parallel RC circuit.

[image]

The supposed Thevenin equivalent.

[image]

Blue is the parallel RC-Circuit and green the Thevenin equivalent. I think the behaviour of the two circuits is apparent. Also, if we derive the transfer function for the circuits, we get two different solutions.

Transfer function for parallel RC-Circuit:

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

Transfer function for thevenin equivalent:

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

Comment: Yes it should, did you forget to halve the voltage to get the same curve?

Comment: That's right. I should have seen that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage of the Thevanized circuit is only half that of the original.

Comment: Specifically, V2=V1/2 for proper representation.